# Use Function Parameters as Values?

Tags: javascript, function, 2d, game-physics, collision

I've been beginning to pick up JavaScript lately, and I'm trying to make a small platformer. I have basic functions down like gravity, movement, and object creation. But I wanted to make worldbuilding a bit easier, so I made a function to create blocks. Everything works just fine, but to create collision between the player and the blocks, I wanted to be able to take the variables from those specific blocks, and use that to stop my character. Right now I set the block to a variable, and try to call that variable, but it comes out red. Is there anyway I can fix that? Or is there a better way to do collision?

Not all code is shown here, just the relevant stuff.

```js
var b1;

function block(x, y, w, h, color) {
    c.fillStyle = color;
    c.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

function update() {
  if((pX >= b1.x - pW) && (pY >= b1.y - pH)) {
        pX = b1.x - pW;
  }
}

function draw() {
  b1 = block(500, 350, 100, 100, 'gray');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions to create [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) using the [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

This is not the only way to create objects, there are many, however it is the closest match to he code you have.

[Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) are a fundamental build block of JavaScript (like Java's class) and it will pay to get a deeper understanding before launching into using them

### Basic examples

```
// It is customary for object instantiated via new to have capitalized names
function Block(x, y, w, h, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
}
var b1 = new Block(500, 350, 100, 100, 'gray');
drawBlock(b1);

function drawBlock(block) {
    ctx.fillStyle = block.color;
    ctx.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.w, block.h);
}

function update() {
  if((pX >= b1.x - pW) && (pY >= b1.y - pH)) {
        pX = b1.x - pW;
  }
}
```

or

```
// It is customary for object instantiated via new to have capitalized names
function Block(x, y, w, h, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
}
Block.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    },
};

var b1 = new Block(500, 350, 100, 100, 'gray');
b1.draw();
```

or

```
const Block = (x, y, w, h) => ({x, y, w, h});// this method does not require new operator
var b1 = Block(500, 350, 100, 100, 'gray');
drawBlock(b1);
function drawBlock(block) {
    ctx.fillStyle = block.color;
    ctx.fillRect(block.x, block.y, block.w, block.h);
}
```

or

```
const blockCommon = {
    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    },
};
const Block = (x, y, w, h) => ({x, y, w, h, ...blockCommon});
var b1 = Block(500, 350, 100, 100, 'gray');
b1.draw();
```

or a dozen or more ways to create objects.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR TELLING ME THIS this is super helpful. But I was also wondering if there was a way to make the collision global. So b1.x would just be one object, but is there a way to call the variables for every object, or do I need to write collision code for ever block I make?

Comment: @Loaphs A general programming tip that covers almost every language. If you find yourself repeating any code, you are doing it wrong and there is a better way. Create a function `update`  with two arguments `p, b`  where `p` references an obj that encapsulates `pX`, `pW` etc... eg `p.x, p.w` etc, and `b` is a `Block` like object The function will look like `function update(p, b) { if ((p.x >= b.x - p.w) && (p.y >= b.y - p.h)) {  p.x = b.x - p.w;} }` and can be use for any `block` and `p` (Whatever that is) and you will never have to write that function again.